# Произношение слов с НН

Tags: фонетика, орфоэпия

Большинство слов с удвоенной Н все произносят с удлинением Н. Но есть слова, которые я и, как мне кажется, большинство произносят так, как если бы они писались с одним Н, то есть Н произносят коротко. Мне пока вспомнилось такие слова: *маринованный, аннотация, сделанный (напр., сделанное дело, **но не** сделанный кем-то сапог), приготовленный*. Причём, если второе и третье слово ещё можно прочитать длинно, то первое и последнее, если так прочитаешь, звучат неестественно.
Так вот, вопрос: от чего зависят эти различие в произнесении НН, чем выделяются эти слова из других, то есть какую тут можно проследить закономерность.
Я заметил лишь то, что в этих словах предшествующая НН гласная находится в безударной позиции.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По-моему, часто это  зависит от индивидуальной манеры в произношении. Но закономерности и какие-то нормы всё же есть.

В русских словах сочетания двух одинаковых согласных произносятся на стыке морфем :приставки и корня ( рассада ), корня и суффикса ( лунный, барабанный ). Слитное произношение предлога и слова также приводит к удвоению согласного, напр.: об берег, под домом., в иноязычных словах двойные согласные могут быть долгими и в корнях слов.Так как долгота звуков не свойственна фонематической системе р. языка, иноязычные слова при освоении часто утрачивают долготу([тонэл'])

**Как правило** удвоенный согласный произносится в том случае, если находится в заударном слоге, напр.: ванна, касса.

В суффиксах –ЕНН, -ОНН, -ОВА(НН) произносится всегда удвоенное Н (НН). Напр.: революционный, экскурсионный, соломенный, организованный, мобилизованный и др.

Однако во многих случаях удвоенный согласный в словах не произносится. Такое произношение наблюдается :

а) в предударной позиции, напр.: балласт, беллетристика, грамматика, аккуратный, аппетит, коллоквиум.

б) в конце слова, напр.: металл, грамм, грипп.

По нормам современного русского литературного языка во многих  словах допускается вариативное произношение двойного согласного, если хотите произносить правильно, нужно проверять по орфоэпическому словарю.

Comment: Спасибо! Отличный ответ! Только, например, в английском 'tunnel' N тоже звучит коротко.

Comment: В английском при чтении двойных согласных нет звуковых удвоений. Вам попадались исключения в транскрипции?

Comment: Да, я так не пытался перебирать слова, но у меня было ощущение, что их может вообще не быть.

Comment: Это я к тому написал, что Людмила написала: "иноязычные слова при освоении часто утрачивают долготу". И я не понимаю, где это долгота есть.

Comment: А Вы считаете, у нас заимствования только из английского языка?